# Raspberry refuses to change IP

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running raspin on an Raspberry Pi2 and I have configured it to have a staic IP on eth0 but it never changes it sticks to its DHCP lease. This is what I have in the interfaces-file under networking.

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.60
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Have I done anything wrong? Am I blind? :)

Comment: You can add a rule in your router to provide your pi with static IP always.

Comment: Seems like that is what I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer to your question, but a workaround.
Add a static IP lease rule in your DHCP server, this is going to be your router in most cases.

Comment: That was I ended up doing.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try restarting network?

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Ye that and ifup/ifdown and restarted the machine no change.

Comment: Strange, it seems all right. Is there any other rule in /etc/network/interfaces file? Is there a "auto eth0" line before that?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the RPi or network - the edited interfaces file doesn't take effect until you do that. Some routers also don't like you requesting a certain IP, so you can also set it to DHCP on the RPi and configure the router so that it always assigns a certain IP to the device.